# Is "into " used just for physical motion?

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know, we use "into " when  some kind of physical  motion is involved. Example as follows :

1)He went into the city.

But sometimes I see that "into " is used without physical motion. Example as follows :

2) India went into semifinal. (it's one kind of motion, but not physical. It's a change of state)

Could you tell me whether "into " will be used in any kind of motion?

Comment: The airplane went into a dive. The ice-skater went into a spin. The economy went into a tailspin. Those are defined motions which involve a state.

Comment: -1 The first thing to do, before posting here, is to ***look in a dictionary***, such as *[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/into)*, read the definitions, and read the example sentences.

Comment: @Clare I did what you said but haven't gotten anything I wanted to know.

Comment: Then you should indicate *why* you didn't. Because we don't want to guess why you didn't. For example, take definition 6 from Oxford. How did reading that definition and the example sentences for it *not* help you?

Answer (score 1):

Generally "**[into](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/into)**" means "**to or toward the inside of**".

- He went **into** the bar.
- The car drove **into** the garage.
- The coin fell **into** the pocket.

It can be used to indicate "**entry**", "**introduction**", "**insertion**", "**superposition**", "**inclusion**" or "**period of time or an extent of space part of which is passed or occupied**".

- He went **into** the city. - this is a **physical motion** *(entered the city)*.

It may in some cases be relatively close to "**against *(to a position of contact with)***" - ***(used to describe hitting or touching something)***

- India went **into** semifinal. - means that **India made an entry** *(entered semifinal)*

Comment: Could you please  give an example of each of its uses( introduction ", " insertion", "superposition", " inclusion " or "period of time or an extent of space part of which is passed or occupied)??  It will be very very helpful for me to understand clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> into

is used to describe movement to an *enclosed* situation, the situation may be physical or metaphorical.

> The thought went **into** his brain.
>   The car went **into** overdrive.  *(overdrive is the enclosing state)*
>   The bird flew **into** the air.
>   He went **into** disbelief.

In your example

> India went **into** the semifinals.

*semifinals* is the enclosure, so that

> India and Sri Lanka are both **in** the semifinals.

Comment: I appreciate your answer because that's what I wanted to know. But I need further clarification. Could you describe the term  "metaphorical" enclosed situation?  How can "disbelief and semifinal " be enclosed?

Comment: You can think of different "*states*" as being "*enclosures*". "Their enthusiasm grew **into** excitement." "She fell **into** a depression". Where you are either **in** a "*state*" or not. "*Groups*" are also a type of "*enclosure*" or "*set*": finals, semifinals, round of 16, top ten, bottom half. "Their improved performance moved them **into** the top ten."